# Run while(resultset.next()) parallely

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

In java 7 .

I have a query.

```
String sql = "select path, job_id from job_table where status = 'NEW' and rownum <= 5 order by created_date"; 


 ResultSet rows = null; 
 try 
 {  
      conn = getConnection();
      preparedStatement = conn.preparedStatement(sql);
     rows  =preparedStatement.executeQuery();

      while(rows.next())
     {  

  // do stuff or call respective methods depending on the values received from resultset.
```

//suppose row has value 1 or 2 or 3 then

```
 if(rows.contains(1))
    doAnalysis1(param1);

 if(rows.contains(2))
    doAnalysis2(param1);


 if(rows.contains(3))
    doAnalysis3(param1);

   }
 }
```

Now what I is to do stuff parallely. Previously when I run my application actually it completes the other functionality for each row and then processess the next row.  But If I got 3 to 4 rows then it should process all at once.. How this can be achieved? Any example would help me.

Comment: Previously when I run my application actually it completes ....Can you post that previous code (minimal) ? We need to understand what exactly you are doing as ur current question is too broad

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Tim : sorry for my minimal code.. I just want to run my inner while stuff parallely for 5 records.

Comment: @Javaguy : code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for Java 7:

```
private static final int NUM_THREADS = 8; // Can get from runtime to scale to number of cores
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

String sql = "select path, job_id from job_table where status = 'NEW' and rownum <= 5 order by created_date"; 

ResultSet rows = null; 
try 
{  
    conn = getConnection();
    preparedStatement = conn.preparedStatement(sql);
    rows  =preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    while(rows.next())
    {
        // Getting values from ResultSet here, to not assume thread-safety of ResultSet
        final String path = rows.getString("path");
        final int job_id = rows.getInt("job_id");
        futures.add(executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do stuff or call respective methods depending on the values received from resultset.
            }
        });
    }
    // Wait until all finished
    for(Future<?> future : futures) future.get();
}
```

A few considerations:

- You may need to terminate the executor service for shutdown
- You may use Callable interface if you need to get results from your "do stuff"
- You will have a few more exceptions to deal with in your try/catch.
- NUM_THREADS might be 5 in your case?
- Any checked exceptions within run() can be wrapped in RuntimeException then rethrown.  Use of Callable would not need this.

Edit - here is a different order to do things, where your database connection is released earlier:

```
private static final int NUM_THREADS = 8; // Can get from runtime to scale to number of cores
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

String sql = "select path, job_id from job_table where status = 'NEW' and rownum <= 5 order by created_date"; 

try {
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    try (
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.preparedStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rows = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
    ) {
        while(rows.next())
        {
            // Getting values from ResultSet here, to not assume thread-safety of ResultSet
            final String path = rows.getString("path");
            final int job_id = rows.getInt("job_id");
            futures.add(executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do stuff or call respective methods depending on the values received from resultset.
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // Wait until all finished, database is already release while background processing is still ongoing
    for(Future<?> future : futures) future.get();
} catch(...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: My bad. I am using java 7.. Any thing on this?

Comment: I have made the alterations for Java 7.  This code is a guideline of one approach and is not complete, I might have a typo here or there.

Comment: Not sure where you get "param1", you might need to make it final to use within the Runnable.

Comment: It was just for an example. I am trying your code. Hope it works according to my expectations

Comment: I added a second block of code modified a bit to allow the database to be closed early, if appropriate to your use-case.  General rule of thumb is to close/release database connections as early as possible.

Comment: is there any way, by which we can track how many processes are running at an instance and what time is being taken by each of them

Comment: I have seen threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount(). Will this help?